# What does 'which' refer to?

Tags: reference

I wrote the sentence but I'm not sure what 'which' refers to exactly. Does **which** only refer to the holistic understanding of different areas of the businesses?

> The broad knowledge across different areas that top managers hold
> allows them to have a **holistic understanding of different aspects of
> the businesses**, **which** in turn enables them to create innovative
> solutions for complex problems.

Or does **which** refer to entire bold clause?

> **The broad knowledge across different areas that top managers hold
> allows them to have a holistic understanding of different aspects of
> the businesses**, **which** in turn enables them to create innovative
> solutions for complex problems.

Comment: If you wrote the sentence, you must know what you intended to say! I would understand **which** to refer to **top managers having a holistic understanding of different aspects of the businesses**.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I think it also makes sense to understand it as referring to the whole thing of the broad knowledge allowing them to have a holistic understanding. This whole thing enables them to create innovative solutions. That's why I don't know how to analyze 'which'.

Comment: The only way it makes sense to me is "The broad knowledge... allows them to have A, which _in turn_ enables them to do B"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to explain the meaning of ***text created by the querent.*** The referent of ***which*** in the cited text is syntactically ambiguous to us as ***readers***, but we should be able to assume that ***the writer knows what he means.***

Comment: @KateBunting: Despite my previous comment, I think ***in turn*** strongly implies that ***which*** refers back to *[having] **a holistic understanding...*** rather than ***The broad knowledge...*** OR ***allowing...***

Comment: I'd say the antecedent is "to have a holistic understanding of different aspects of the businesses". We understand that "having a holistic understanding of different aspects of the businesses in turn enables them to create innovative solutions for complex problems"

Comment: Fyi, knowledge is not "held".  One has or does not have it.

Comment: @Lambie Meh, it doesn't bother me too much. What does is that "allows them to have" could simply be "gives them." (And "enables them to" could be "lets them.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that it's possible to use pronouns in ways that make it unclear what they refer to. And if you're concerned, maybe it's a clue that you should recast the sentence. But I would argue that the content of *this* sentence makes its intent clear.

> **A** allows them to have **B**, which in turn enables them to create C.

The logic expressed in this syntax makes **B** the reasonable antecedent of "which." The "which in turn" phrase works well with a construction like the one we have here, with two parts using similar verbs ("A frog egg grows into a tadpole, which in turn develops into a frog.") *If* "which" were intended to refer to the entire first clause, then there would be no reason for the "in turn." The only way to remotely make sense of it would be if "in turn" referred to a preceding sentence, but even then it would be an awkward and confusing choice.

Comment: We understand that "having a holistic understanding of different aspects of the businesses in turn enables them to create innovative solutions for complex problems." That should give us a clue as to what the antecedent is.